# Videos en formato m3u8 no se reproduce correctamente en IOS (react native video)

Tags: react-native

estoy desarrollando una app movil que sera usada para capacitaciones en una empresa, pero recientemente se hizo un cambio en las apis y los videos que me mandan en los endpoints ahora estan en formato m3u8, probando con android no tengo ningun inconveniente, sin embargo, en IOS pasa algo curioso. Cuando entro por primera vez a la app y selecciono cualquier video si lo reproduce, sin embargo cuando ya cuando selecciono otro, el componente de react-native-video "carga" el video, pero la pantalla se queda en negro y no manda ningun error, es como si algo lo estuviera bloqueando.
Ya especifique en la propiedad type del source que sea m3u8, pase las cookies que me solicitan y quite la propiedas cache, si alguien le ha pasado algo similar, seria de ayuda, gracias.

```
<Video
              ref={(val) => {
                setVideoRef(val);
              }}
              source={{
                uri: url,
                type:"m3u8",
                headers: {
                  Cookie: cookies,
                },
              }}
              onLoadStart={() => console.log('Load iniciado')}
              resizeMode="contain"
              onBuffer={onBuffer}
              fullscreen={Platform.OS === 'ios' ? false : isFullScreen}
              onTouchStart={() => setIsShowControls(!isShowControls)}
              style={{
                position: 'absolute',
                top: 0,
                left: 0,
                bottom: 0,
                right: 0,
              }}
              controls={false}
              muted={mute}
              onLoad={onLoad}
              paused={paused}
              onProgress={onProgress}
              selectedTextTrack={{type: 'language', value: language}}
              textTracks={subtitles}
              onEnd={changeFinish}
              volume={volume}
            />
```